# Distributional limit of $m\sin(m|x^2+y^2-1|)$

Tags: integration, distribution-theory

Consider the sequence
$$
f_m(x,y)=m\sin(m|x^2+y^2-1|)
$$
as sequence of distributions in $\mathcal{D}^\prime(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\})$. What is the limit as $m\to\infty$? In other words, given a smooth function $\varphi$ with compact support contained in $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$, what is
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}\int f_m(x,y)\varphi(x,y)\,dxdy?
$$

Comment: Have you got the solution? I have tried but haven't manage to get anything that feels right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that by an easy substitution
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\int_0^{2\pi} rm\sin(m|1-r^2|)\varphi_r(r,\phi)\,d\phi\,dr&=\frac12\int_0^1m\sin(mx)\varphi_r(\sqrt{1-x})\,dx\\&\phantom{=}+\frac12\int_0^\infty m\sin(mx)\varphi_r(\sqrt{1+x})\,dx.
\end{align}
Here, we set $\int_0^{2\pi}\varphi(r,\phi)\,d\phi=\varphi_r(r)$. Using integration by parts in both integrals, it is easy to see that the right-hand side converges to $\varphi_r(1)$. In summary, $f_m\to f$ in $\mathcal{D}^\prime(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\})$ where
$$
\langle f,\varphi\rangle=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\varphi(1,\phi)\,d\phi.
$$