# Let $f_n(x)=n\sin(n\vert x\vert)$. Find $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$ in $\mathcal D'(\mathbb R).$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, solution-verification, distribution-theory

**Problem:** For $n\in\mathbb N$, let
$$f_n(x)=n\sin(n\vert x\vert)\quad\text{for }x\in\mathbb R.$$
Find the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$ in $\mathcal D'(\mathbb R).$

**My Attempt:** Let $\psi\in\mathcal D(\mathbb R)$. Doing an integration by parts we have
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty n\sin(n\vert x\vert)\psi(x)\,dx
&=-\int_{-\infty}^0n\sin(nx)\psi(x)\,dx+\int_0^\infty n\sin(nx)\psi(x)\,dx\\
&=2\psi(0)-\int_{-\infty}^0\cos(nx)\psi'(x)\,dx+\int_0^\infty\cos(nx)\psi'(x)\,dx.
\end{align*}
By the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^0\cos(nx)\psi'(x)\,dx=0\quad\text{and}\quad\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\infty\cos(nx)\psi'(x)\,dx=0.$$
It follows that
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n\sin(n\vert x\vert)=2\delta_0\quad\text{in }\mathcal D'(\mathbb R).$$

---

Do you agree with my proof? If not, please let me know why.
Thank you for your time and appreciate any feedback.

Comment: At least your answer is correct. I got the same result [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3849775/168433).

Comment: As you can see in my calculation, the limits of $\int \cos(nx) \psi'(x) \, dx$ can be shown directly. But the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma should also be fine.